# How to use parent result in sub selects?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to do something like that:

```
Select 
(select sum(monkey_value) from mt where monkey_weight > 20) ,
(select sum(monkey_value) from mt where monkey_weight > 30) 
from MonkeyTable mt where monkeySanityLevel > 10
```

but i cant use mt in subselects. What ive done right now is that i declared an table and pass the result of parent value into it, and right after i make the subselcts in query for itself.

Are there any smarter ways so i can avoid inserting rows into temp table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Select 
Sum(case when monkey_weight > 20 then monkey_value else 0 end) as WT20, 
Sum(case when monkey_weight > 30 then monkey_value else 0 end) as WT30 
from MonkeyTable mt where monkeySanityLevel > 10
```

Comment: it works, but what if i have multiple limits like : monkey_weight > 20 and monkey_NumberOfFingers > 100? its telling me that i cant do it because agreagation can not be used on sub selects

Comment: You can have multiple conditions within the case statement eg case when monkey_weight >20 and Monkey Number of fingers > 100 then monkey_weight else 0 end

Answer (score 1):

following should work:

```
select sum(case when monkey_weight > 20 then monkey_value end) as monkey_weight_20,
        sum(case when monkey_weight > 30 then monkey_value end) as monkey_weight_30
from MonkeyTable mt 
where monkeySanityLevel > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but here's one more that might do the trick, using a CTE:

```
with mt as
(
    select *
    from MonkeyTable
    where monkeySanityLevel > 10
)
select
    sum(select monkey_value from mt where monkey_weight > 20) as WT20,
    sum(select monkey_value from mt where monkey_weight > 30) as WT30
```

Or another option, with a single subquery rather than a CTE:

```
select sum(WT20) WT20, sum(WT30) WT30
from
(
    select 
        case when monkey_weight > 20 then monkey_value else 0 end WT20,
        case when monkey_weight > 30 then monkey_value else 0 end WT30
    from MonkeyTable
    where monkeySanityLevel > 10
) mt
```